ESP8266 Software Watchdog triggers while http communication
I am using an ESP8266 to get some data off an openDTU (as JSON file) to act as a status monitor.
While getting the data from the openDTU the ESP8266's software watchdog "bites" every few minutes.
I tried using
ESP.wdtEnable(5000); 

in setup() to make the watchdog very forgiving and added several ESP.wtdFeed() commands in the critical area of the code:
            ESP.wdtFeed();
        http.begin(client, getLink6);
        ESP.wdtFeed();
        httpCode = http.GET();       
        getWarOkay = false;
        ESP.wdtFeed();
        if ( httpCode > 0 ) { 
            payload = http.getString(); 
            getWarOkay = true;
            payloadAll = payloadAll + "<br><br>httpCode: " + String(httpCode) + "<br>###" + payload + "### END-PAYLOAD4 ###";
        }
        else { anzFehler++; textFehler = textFehler + "Block1"; }
        ESP.wdtFeed();
        
        http.end();

Still it will trigger a reboot - maybe a little less often than earlier
Serial monitor output is: rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
I guess I will not be able to speed up the response time of the openDTU easily - Any suggestions how to deal with the issue?

If your code has a fundamental memory problem or stackoverflow, adding ESP.wdtFeed() will only prolong the crash, it does not address the foundamental issue. So you need to show your code. Sending an HTTP request (as you show) would not trigger the watchdog, it is somewhere else...

Thanks - I thought the rst cause 2 would indicate a soft watchdog reset and a memory leak would show in the error message. I need to step deeper into the matter

After streamlining the code and optimizing response times I was able to keep the ESP8266 running for about 2h before a reset triggered. "rst cause:4"
Then I found an article about ESP8266 optimized libraries that I already uses in my code - those were
ESP8266HTTPClient.h, ESP8266WiFi.h and ESP8266mDNS.h

AND one extra general WiFi.h I have probably copied from an example I found without noticing I had the optimized ESP8266WiFi.h already in play.
This did not result in an error but, since the WiFi.h was included after the ESP8266WiFi.h it did most likely just replace the optimized with the general include.
With the WiFi.h include removed from the code the devices have been up 24h without a reset.
